# HTTP to HTTPS redirection session variable lost

Tags: java, session, https, websphere, websphere-portal

After user coming to our site , they are redirected, from http://sitename.com to https://sitename.com.

We are storing some variable in httpsession in when customer 1st come to our site.
But after landing on https those variables are lost.

Same code is working fine in testing environment .Both environment have multiple nodes under one cluster .

code is in :JAVA

We are using Websphere application server 8.5 
Websphere portal 8

can anyone suggest any parameter we need to tune in production?

Comment: When is the redirection happening?  Is it when the user user logs in or as soon as the user hits the http site?  How are you doing the redirection?  Is it done in a portlet? a servlet? login filter?

Answer (score 1):

I expect your JSESSIONID cookie is set to be https-only, which is a [recommended security feature](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cprs_best_practice.html), but which can be changed in the WebSphere settings.
[image]